Why are there so few people of sub-Saharan African descent in the lands of the former Ottoman Empire compared to the Americas?
Starkey's assertions about Islamic slavery are predicated on the following assumptions.  Are these plausible? What data is available on which to better compare Islamic and European slavery frameworks?
NOTE: This question is not redundant; it is an attempt to separate the two questions. (A) What do we know about Ottoman/Islamic and slavery in the Americas? What data exists that we can use for analysis? (The focus of this question.) (B) Based on data about the two slavery frameworks, what conclusions can we reach about the consequences for enslaved persons? (The other question.)

Around 12 million Africans were transported to the Americas during the Atlantic Slave Trade.
A comparable number of sub-Saharan Africans were transported into the Ottoman Empire over a similar time frame.
There are a large number of people of African descent in the Americas today, perhaps as many as 100 million.
There are far fewer people of sub-Saharan African descent in the lands of the former Ottoman Empire. Turkey, the empire's legal successor, only has a few thousand citizens of African descent. Saudi Arabia and Iraq have perhaps 2 million and 1 million citizens of African descent respectively.

(I will leave to one side the former Ottoman provinces in North Africa, which have seen older and deeper influxes of sub-Saharans than Early Modern chattel slavery, e.g. the Twenty-Fifth Dynasty, Sultan Ismail's Black Guard.)
If we accept the above points, we are then forced to ask: Why did the victims of the Ottoman Slave Trade leave so few descendants? A number of explanations have come to my attention, some of which seem plausible, others of which are less credible:

David Starkey made a controversial claim, explaining that the discrepancy was due to the extreme cruelty of the Ottoman slave-masters. This claim is examined in a separate question.
Others have claimed that the people imported from sub-Saharan Africa were mostly male, and, one way or another, were prevented from reproducing.
Others still have pointed to the (mostly) non-hereditary nature of Ottoman slavery, contrasting this with the strongly hereditary character of slavery in the New World. Perhaps sub-Saharan Ottoman slaves did leave numerous descendants, but those descendants, never having formed a separate caste, are mixed into the rest of the population much more thoroughly than in the Americas.

And there may well be other hypotheses which have not yet come to my attention. In any case, I would be very grateful if the community was able to examine this question.

I should warn you that "well established" assertions in questions tend to not go over well. Upon investigation an appalling number of them end up being false. Worse, making unsupported false assertions foundational to a question is a common tool of trolls here, as sort a way to get us to say what they want by injecting the rhetorical equivalent of a divide by 0. If its really "well known" or "well established" then it should be trivial to find a reference backing up the assertion.

@BrianZ - No, its not a dup, and I specifically asked this to be moved to a separate question. "Are these (it turns out completely wrong) statements supported by facts?" Is a completely different question than "OK then, what's the real reason?"

@T.E.D. By all means, put your refutation of #2 into an answer. If you can back it up with evidence, that would be an excellent answer to the question I asked.

@TomHosker - as the asker, the onus is upon you to back up assertions in your question.

The problem with this question is the only implicit conjecture that the Atlantic slave trade can be somehow paralleled to the slave trade to the Ottoman empire. But while the first is a reasonably delimitable phenomenon – people from Africa traded to the Americas by means of ship transport – the other is not. Through the Arab world, there were many trade routes, dynasties, states and regions from North Africa to Southeast Asia, slaves came from all over Africa and Europe, and the time frame spans one and a half millenia. Singleing out black Africans sold to the Ottomans seems very artificial.

Voting to close. It's a focus issue. It would be more clear that this is a separate question if it wasn't based on so many of the same unsupported assumptions.  Asking how many African slaves were brought to the Ottoman empire would be a challenging enough but appropriate question. Instead, this question assumes a very large number without providing a source and then goes further to make more assumptions.

I think that there have been enough revisions to purge comments. @BrianZ do you agree?

@MCW The first 4-5 comments are a bit stale but I think the rest are relevant until this either gets revised or closed to focus on a single clear question of historical fact.

@BrianZ - I have to admit, I started looking into this, and just finding a good number of sub-saharan African slaves sent to Ottoman territory is really challenging all on its own. Numbers I can get are all over the place, and the Arab slave trade was something like 800 years older (so do those 800 years count for the purposes of this question? A case could be made either way) I will say the numbers I'm finding are also surprisingly high (to me at least).

I think it is a fascinating question, showing the deep Christian misunderstanding of the old Muslim nations. +1

It should be noted that slave breeding as an important feature of slave demographics was quite unique of the United States. In other places, a slave population was maintained by a steady import of mostly young male slaves, who didn't reproduce. For example, several south American countries had large slave populations that mostly vanished when slave trade ended. I think that the proportion of number of African slaves imported versus present day African descent inhabitants would be wildly different for different countries, and the United States are more likely than Turkey to be an outlier.

I feel bad for suggesting this question, then not answering it. My issue hasn't been that I don't have theories, but rather that it would take way more research than I was expecting to support or refute them. I'll leave here what I have: My suspicion is that it mostly has to do with how the slaves were employed. The Ottomans (it appears) mostly used domestic (and often sex) slaves, while Europeans mostly used them for mass menial labor on large plantations.

" In other places, a slave population was maintained by a steady import of mostly young male slaves, who didn't reproduce. "  What kept them from reproducing?  There's records that indicted slaves from sub-Sahara Africa were routinely castrated.  Slaves taken from Europe would also be castrated but this was more the exception than the rule.  What could also keep them from reproducing was that only male slaves would be brought to the area, any females from sub-Sahara Africa taken as slaves would be sold elsewhere or if enslaved in the area they'd be separate from any men as domestic servants.

This question is similar to: Was the European slave market in the East during the colonial era similar to the transatlantic slave market? If not (less brutal, etc), why?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@T.E.D. - As you noted, there are no hard numbers on slave trade from Africa. But there are very good estimates. As well as there are assertions out there that do not match reality. I.e. castration - African males were castrated before sale to the level of 90%, but Europeans were hardly ever - males were ransomed, females were taken as wives mor more often concubines. Ottomans had huge slave labor pool domestically (dhimmis), so they didn't need workers, unlike Colonials in Central/South America and Oceania, just sex slaves and servitors.

The answer is simple, slaves brought from sub-Sahara were routinely castrated while those from Europe were not.  The details can get complicated though.
Islamic law prohibited castration of slaves but had no prohibition on having eunuchs as slaves.  Eunuchs were valued in the Ottoman Empire for a variety of reasons which meant there was considerable value for various tribes taking men as slaves in raids, having them castrated outside any Muslim controlled territory, then have them marched north over the Sahara to be sold.
In addition to Islamic law prohibiting the castration of slaves it would be bad politics for the Ottoman Empire to castrate any men captured as slaves from Europe.  If word got out that the Ottomans were killing or "mutilating" captured Europeans then that would create far more tension than just taking them as slaves.  A captured European could be sold for ransom if returned in relative good health.  It may be better for them politically to have captured Europeans found dead than castrated since the death could have been from an accident, battle, or some other European than an Ottoman, whichever the case the person is not alive to tell tales.  Europeans that were found alive and castrated means the victim can point out who was responsible.  With few intermediary nations/tribes/whatever between Europeans and the Ottomans willing to capture and castrate men to be sold as slaves to the Ottomans the men would be left intact and able to produce children later.
There were certainly all kinds of exceptions to the general trends but for the most part sub-Saharan Africans taken as slaves would be left intact if sent to the Americas but routinely castrated if sent elsewhere.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I thought this was fairly common knowledge among students of history for this region and era.  Plenty of sources to be found in the references section on the Wikipedia page on the topic.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_Ottoman_Empire

I will not repost my whole answer on a very similar topic here from the original, so I'll link it and just do the highlights relevant to this question.
And the answer is that you are starting from several false premises, quite popular:

The Eastern-bound trade route was bigger (by about 20 percent) than the trans-Atlantic direction,
Treatment and conditions of the slaves in Americas was often as brutal - if not more so - than the one by Ottomans. However, slavery in Islam is well defined, so David Starkey has some arguments on his side, pointing out that sex slavery and children borne by sex slaves is governed by Islamic tradition and killing own slaves was allowed without repercussions,
Mortality rate for the Ottoman-bound route was much, much higher than the Western-bound one. It is estimated that it could go as high as 80-85%,
Assuming that in the Islamic territories slaves may have been treated about the same as in the Americas, due to the overall harsher living conditions and overall poverty, they had much less chance of survival than in the West,
Also, slave trade fulfilled different demand - West required labor, East required mostly sex slavery and servitors. In other words, Ottoman Empire imported mostly women and eunuchs, which, by definition, cannot procreate (and castration was, in general, the reason for abnormally high mortality rate for slaves), and the reason was that Ottomans had large slave workforce already available in place (dhimmis), but which, for ideological-religious reasons could not be used in any other way as labor,
And finally, also due to ideological-religious reasons, Ottoman Empire was ALSO acquiring slaves in the whole of Europe, but mostly Eastern and Central European countries, which "market" could rival in numbers the African slave route (somewhere between 10 and 16 million slaves).

There is, of course, possibility that there was some progeny from the relationships between African Women, rare non-castrate African men and Arab overlords, but it's highly unlikely, given the status assigned to Black People by Qur'an, that they would be successful in integrating into Ottoman Empire's society in any meaningful way. And it's not even a problem of being a slave, because history knows a number of prominent slaves in Islam, but of the issue of being of Arab or non-Arab descent, with prohibition on enslaving Arabs.


What is the basis for the high volume estimates for the Ottoman slave trade from Africa? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_Ottoman_Empire has numbers that are much lower than the transatlantic slave trade (in the late 19th century, i.e. after European slave supply had dried up)



"sex slavery" and "(only) some progeny" sounds a bit contradictory?


@Jan People, in general, knew about bird and bees stuff... There are ways to introduce a gap between one and the other. In addition, because what we're talking is African slave trade and Islam is pretty straightforward about the role and place of Black People, I seriously doubt that mixed-race children would be tolerated, let alone accepted, in the Middle Age Ottoman Empire.

@jan All the sources for all kinds of slave trade routes are in the answer I linked to text.

10% of Saudi Arabia's population is made up of descendants of former slaves. Many of them are quite famous like the legendary former footballer Majed Abdullah, former Imam of Mecca, Adil al-Kalbani, and general Ahmed Asiri.
Other countries like Oman, Yemen and Iraq have similar proportions of black citizens of African descent.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The DNA of former black slaves of the Ottoman Empire is now happily mixed with the DNA of modern Turks, Algerians, Libyans, Greeks, and all people from former Ottoman vassals or provinces.
All blacks from Africa or their children sooner or later became Muslims and thus ceased to be slaves. There was no racial discrimination or segregation in the Ottoman Empire, so they mixed freely.
The Ottoman Empire imported even more Slavic slaves from Crimea. For the same reasons, there are no old, distinct white/blond ethnic groups in these former provinces.
Being a Turk was not a question of blood, facial features, or color. It was only a question of religion and language. Yes, civic rights were scarce, and a Turk Noble had fewer rights than an American docker, but that Noble could be black, white, or yellow.
Another, lesser reason: don't forget, that slaves from modern Djibouti or Somalia, did not belong to the black race, even being Subsaharian. Black tribes live to the South starting from Kenya. (I am not sure about the Somaly/Kenya border tribes). So, only about part of Subsaharian slaves were black.
One more reason. (It can hardly be evaluated.) The beauty ideal for both men and women in all nations under Ottoman power was white. So, black people usually had fewer chances to get children. And a person with lighter skin had more chances.
The Turks started as a white and blond tribe. At least, they claim it. My Turk acquaintants did - all of them. And they said that they became swarthy due to mixing with black slaves. And nobles could buy more expensive white slaves. That's the result. I am afraid that the precise picture can be done by the archeological genetic expertise only. And until it is done, we can only speculate.

Citations needed

One thing that I think backs this answer up a bit: Check out this map of the modern distribution of sickle-cell trait, which we are pretty certain evolved in sub-Saharan African populations. Pretty much the entire Mediterranean coast historically had malaria (so the genes would be useful all around), yet the area that today has the genetic trait is clearly centered on the Bosphorous.

I like this answer, and I think that your explanation is plausible, but there are some serious errors in it which I cannot pass over in silence: (1) 'All blacks from Africa or their children sooner or later became Muslims and thus ceased to be slaves.' If the slave of a non-Muslim master converted to Islam, he was automatically free, but otherwise conversion did not entail manumission. (2) 'There was no racial discrimination or segregation in the Ottoman Empire'. This is patently untrue, and you contradict it yourself later on in your answer.

(3) 'The Ottoman Empire imported even more Slavic slaves from Crimea.' Yes, and if you visit Istanbul - as I have done - you will see plenty of native Turks with blond hair and blue eyes. Atatürk himself, and several of the sultans, are prime examples of this. The evidence is of course anecdotal, but I don't see comparable numbers of Afro-Turks. (4) '[S]laves from modern Djibouti or Somalia, did not belong to the black race'. The question of who is or is not black is controversial. Notice that I have always tried to sidestep the issue by using geographical, and not racial, classifications.

(5) 'The beauty ideal for both men and women in all nations under Ottoman power was white.' As I understand it, the Ottoman beauty ideal was for the skin to be white BUT for the eyes and hair to be as dark as possible. Hence the most expensive slave girls were the Circassians, who conformed to this ideal, and not the Slavs, who often had blue eyes and fair hair.

@TomHosker Please, where do I contradict it?

@Gangnus So the contradiction I had in mind was that at one point you say that there was no racial discrimination in the Ottoman Empire, but then later on comment masters preferred sex-slaves with fairer skin. On reflection, I can see the other side of this; are sexual preferences really a form of discrimination, even in invidious circumstances?

@Gagnus But - in the nicest way possible - your blanket assertion that '[t]here was no racial discrimination or segregation in the Ottoman Empire' is silly. Bigots are like cockroaches; they exist, to some extent, more or less everywhere. If you want a specific example: consider the Imperial Harem, where there were distinct sections accessible to black eunuchs - who lost all their genitalia - and white eunuchs - who "only" lost their testicles. Was the Ottoman Slave Trade less racist than its Atlantic counterpart? Yes, I think so. But that's not what you wrote.

@TomHosker Let's distinguish discrimination by law, discrimination by tradition, and discrimination by personal taste. The question compares the USA separate race group of black citizens and the lack of a such group in Turkey. But in the USA blacks were discriminated by law. So, in my first point, I am talking about the state/law discrimination. And the personal tastes that I mention in the 3d point, have nothing to do with it. Those are two different mechanisms, even if their outputs influence each other

@TomHosker Muslim slaves in the O.E.? Have you read any mention of it? The base set of laws in the O.E. is Sharia. And it strictly forbids the enslavery of Muslims.

@TomHosker (3) As for the whiteness of the Turk Elite... The Turks started as a white and blond tribe. At least, they claim it. My Turk acquaintants did - all of them. And they said that they became swarthy due to mixing with black slaves. And nobles could buy more expensive white slaves. That's the result. I am afraid, that the precise picture can be done by the archeological genetic expertise only. And until it is done, we can only speculate.

@TomHosker speaking of anecdotal, I have seen claims that terms slav and slave are etymologically related, although this has more to do with the slave trade passing through Europe to Muslim Spain.

@RogerV. It is highly possible that those famous claims (Slav = slave) were invented by the propaganda of the Polish gentry, who claimed descent from the Sarmatians, whereas their farmers were Slavs and thus considered as natural slaves or "bydlo" (cattle in Polish). This convenient explanation justified the reappearance of slavery in Poland in the 16th century and continued to be used until the 20th century. In reality, the reasons were purely economic, see the three-volume work of Braudel. "Folk etymology" lies almost always.

@Gangnus I saw this claim some time ago in a  popular history text (or perhaps another book by the same author), which was strongly revisionist in respect to "official/school" history as taught in France - it is possible that the claim was inserted there along with other controversial issues, without much foundation... but it seems to have followers well beyond Poland.

@RogerV. Without any doubt, well beyond. As I said  - it is a famous claim. Many Russian historians believed in that, too. But the theory had to appear somewhere and for some reason.  For French or English it is a piece of neutral information - did the word Slav descend from slave or didn't. But the Polish gentry needed that theory.

@Gangnus here the context is that early medieval Europe actively supplied slavic slaves to Muslim caliphate, hence words "esclave/slave" replaced latin "servus" - the first link that popped up

@RogerV. Sorry, that article cannot be an argument by itself. It can be merely an example of shallow quality of the popular science articles. For example, it claims Russian farmers till 1861 to be serves, whereas they were not subjects of the law, they were goods for trade, and thus, according to this very article, they were slaves.  As for slaves/Slav argumentation, the article merely repeats the claim we were discussing.  Here is not a bit of information about the source of this claim or any logical arguments for the claim.

@Gangnus I am not citing this article as a proof of this claim - just pointing out that it occurs in different context, which is not so neutral for western Europeans.

@RogerV. Then, of course, it IS an argument by itself. Sorry, I didn't understand your target... But still, "Here is not a bit of information about the source of this claim or any logical arguments for the claim." Only the claim itself.

@Gangnus from what I see, popular etimologies routinely cite "slav" as the origin of "slave/esclave" in modern languages. Wikipedia article on slavery says that this was the view prevalent in the 19th century, but since questioned - with multiple citations in support of either hypothesis. This study says that the word is so old, that we cannot know for sure (for the shortage of written records)... but the author is likely Polish, so they might be not free of bias - in view of what you said previously.

@RogerV. I don't think, that Polish author in 20th century was biased. He simply repeated what he heard at school. BTW, I, in the USSR school, heard the same version. The truest phase is yours from the previous comment: "the word is so old, that we cannot know for sure". Any versions are merely supposed. We have to wait for finding some unknown document.
